# Theory of the control pin of a 555

Tags: 555

I have been using a 555 timer to modulate an audio signal and it works as expected, but I wonder how.

[image: Async 555]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/3En1cbzuaAak.png))</sub>

If I am right, when the control voltage pin is positive, the "trigger points" get to CV and CV/2, but what happens when \$ CV \leq 0\$, as it does with an audio signal ?

Are potentials below zero simply clipped because of the comparators ?

Comment: A capacitor  is not the same thing as a wire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CV is tied to the inverting input of the top comparator, therefore it is biased at 2/3 Vcc due to the internal resistor network.

[image: 555 block diagram]

Comment: Doesn't it change since the control pin is used ?

Comment: Do you understand what "biased" means?

Comment: Do you mean biased as in default value ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing

Comment: So following that definition, the input signal at pin 5 effectively "replaces" the 2/3 value. What would happen if it were negative ?

Comment: Except that capacitors block DC.

Comment: As it is an audio signal, it varies and it is sometimes negative, that is what I meant.

Comment: At which point it pulls the biased voltage down. But the control voltage never goes negative unless you've done something horribly wrong.

Comment: So you mean that applying for instance directly -1V to pin 5 won't change the voltage of the comparator to minus one , but only pull it down, even if it is directly connected in the schematic you provided?

Comment: The capacitor in the schematic means that the voltage is never applied to it; it is decoupled by the capacitor which means that the audio signal swings around the bias voltage. This is one of the **basic tenets** of audio electronics.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now. Thank you for your help and your patience!

Answer (score 4):

The frequency of the 555 astable is controlled by the capacitor being charged between 1/3rd and 2/3rds of the supply voltage. These reference voltages are set by three internal (trimmed)resistors - each 5k (hence the name, 555).

To understand how we produce frequency modulation we only need to consider what is happening to these (comparator) reference voltages when we vary the control voltage.

[image]

**Circuit (1)** shows the input circuit as we would normally think about it. The control voltage in this case is an audio signal. We add a capacitor (C) to block any DC component. With no AC or just DC input (blocked by the capacitor,C) the internal reference voltages will be 2/3rd (Vhigh) and 1/3 (Vlow).

**Circuit 2:** From an **AC point of view**  the supply lines are connected together so R1 will be in parallel with R2 + R3. This gives an input resistance of about 3k3 (5k//10k). This allows us to calculate a suitable value for C. The circuit formed is a high pass filter so C must be big enough to pass the lowest frequencies required. Let's choose 20Hz. This gives a value of around 2u2.

**Circuit 3.** If the high and low references simply moved up and down by the same amount the charge and discharge times would remain the same so the frequency would not vary.

Looking at the (ac input) circuit the high reference voltage changes by the **full** control input but the low voltage reference only changes by **half** the control signal.

The result is that **the voltage between the two references changes by half the amplitude of the audio input**.

As the voltage difference between high/low references increases the output frequency decreases (more time to charge/discharge), as the voltage difference decreases the output frequency increases (less time to charge/discharge).

This is the key to understanding how the 555 produces an fm signal (frequency varying with the audio input).